# do i have to install database on client's system?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019, local-database

I am creating a C# Windows Forms application in Visual Studio 2019 for Car Dealing.

My question are:

1. Should I use local database as only single client on single PC is going to use the app?
2. Will I have to install database on client's PC?

If there is another way, how can I do it?

Comment: Do you need to support multiple users of the same data concurrently? Then you definitely need a full-fledged database, and that typically means installing something (usually on a central server). If your application is strictly single-user, then you could use an "embedded" database that doesn't need any explicit installation (like SQLite or SQL Server Compact Edition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As NeutralHandle mentioned, you can save the data into SQLite.

To use it in Winforms, you can follow the steps.

1.Install System.Data.SQLite from Nuget

2.Configure the connection string in App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
...
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="SQLiteDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

3.Then refer to the code demo.

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.sqlite");

SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite");
m_dbConnection.Open();

string sql = "create table highscores (name varchar(20), score int)";

SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

sql = "insert into highscores (name, score) values ('Me', 9001)";

command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();// read
SQLiteCommand sqlCom = new SQLiteCommand("Select * From highscores", m_dbConnection);

SQLiteDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader();

int i = 1;
while (sqlDataReader.Read())
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(i);
    listBox1.Items.Add(sqlDataReader.GetValue(0));
    listBox1.Items.Add(sqlDataReader.GetValue(1));
    i++;
}

m_dbConnection.Close();
```

Comment: your answer helped me a lot. i don't know who are they who closed my question. I have clearly asked what I wanted. May be the smart one can show me how can I ask the same question i asked in this post. I want it to be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

Sqlite would be a good solution to this.

https://www.sqlite.org/index.html

"SQLite is a C-language library that implements a small, fast, self-contained, high-reliability, full-featured, SQL database engine. SQLite is the most used database engine in the world. SQLite is built into all mobile phones and most computers and comes bundled inside countless other applications that people use every day."